# How to convert current java web application to a portable desktop/mobile application

Tags: java, web, firefox, portable-apps

I have an already built web application (kind of a tutorial) which runs on a touchscreen Kiosk. The application is written in Java and runs on Firefox.

How the application works (Skip reading this if you want):
1) The kiosk has the application locked in to Firefox, i.e. whenever I open Firefox, it connects to www.xyz.com and locks everything else down so the user can only interact with the application and not tamper with anything else on the machine
2) The user chooses from the various options presented on the screen using the touchscreen input. For example, English or Spanish, next or previous etc.
3) The application has some flash videos in it which play automatically and can be replayed paused etc by the user.

Problem: I wish to have the application on a DVD or some such portable device so that the user could run them on their own machine/device. It doesn't have to be touchscreen, the user could click through the options. How could I do this? What all alternatives do I have?

Please let me know if additional information is needed or this is not the best place to ask this question. Thanks!

Comment: Hey, welcome to [SU]! I think this may not be the best place for this question, and currently don't know if the Stack Exchange network has a good home for it. It looks like a programming question, but is too open-ended for [SO] in it's current form (and too open-ended for here if you're wanting a general answer for all applications). If you had a more specific question on how to alter the code it would go there, or a more specific problem (i.e., X isn't working when I move it to a DVD, it gives error Y), then it would probably fit well here.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Darth. I see your point, I'm just hoping that somebody who has done something similar before could help me out.

Comment: Just try copying it to a DVD and see what works and what doesn't work. That might give you more specific errors which might be more on-topic for here. You can click the edit button under your question to update it. Also, once you get enough reputation (20, I think), you can visit the [chat]. A much wider range of topics are allowed there. Good luck with your issue :)